# Style set by JQuery function refreshed after postback

Tags: jquery, asp.net

When page loads the Style of a "lblCustomer" Label  is

```
style="display:inline-block"
```

When I click on radio button list this jquery code runs

```
$('#<%=lblCustomer.ClientID %>').hide();
```

and it changes the style of "lblCustomer" Label to

```
style="display: none;"
```

But when I Click on a Button to fetch records
its style again changes to

```
style="display:inline-block;"
```

There is no Update Panel on the page.
I am surprised how button click changes the style of a control.
Can anyone help me to sort  out this issue.

Comment: This is childish question. Try adding some code or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

when page is posting - it comes back as pure as in the begining - which didnt had - display:block.

you should keepo the status via Js in input element which will be transferred within each postback.

Answer (score 0):

The effect you want can be done WITH an Update Panel.

When the page posts back, you lose the state of the page, unless you pass that state back to the server.  Update Panels allow you to fetch new data w/o doing a full post back, so the page state will not be lost.

What you'll have to do is put an Update Panel around that area that will be updated with new records and add the Button as an external trigger to the Update Panel.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001.aspx